# AForge.Video.FFMPEG used in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, aforge

I use Visual C# 2008 and want to write AVI file from bmp sequences.

I found AForge.Video.VWF but it's just for "vmw3" or "DIB " codecs and I want to use AForge.Video.FFMPEG but it got error.

For example I just code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VideoFileWriter vfw = new VideoFileWriter();
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this `filenotfoundexception`

```
{"The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)":null}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to use AForge.Video.FFMPEG correctly, you have to be sure to include the FFmpeg dll's into your output folder. The easiest way is to add them into your VS project, go on their properties and set the Copy to Output Directory option to "Always".

The FFmpeg binaries used by AForge can be found on the AForge.NET's external folder, typically in *C:\Program Files (x86)\AForge.NET\Framework\Externals\ffmpeg\bin*

Comment: I use nuget and I found this file in ```packages\AForge.NET Framework-2.2.5-(libs only)\Externals\ffmpeg\bin``` of my project.

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest Accord.NET NuGet packages. If you download Accord.Video.FFMPEG from NuGet, the FFMPEG dlls should be installed and included in your output directory automatically.

Comment: I have the latest NuGet package from Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64 and still have this issue.  Was the x64 version corrected as well?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but downloading Accord.Video.FFMPEG will take care of this for you, just remember to build explicitly to x86

using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;

Answer (score 0):

it's happened because this AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL depend upon another dlls. copy all that dll into output folder.