# Debug WebService in Visual Studio: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm writing a WebService that references another managed DLL which then uses a third-party DLL. When I start debugging my WebService I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL' or one of
>   its dependencies.

As recommended in many other posts, I tried these steps:

- Changed from AnyCPU to x86
- Copied all DLLs to %system32% directory

But had no success so far. Any ideas?

Thanks, Matthias

Comment: Does your Web.Config contain any references to this DLL? If so is the version number correct?

Comment: did you cross check the version of the assembly you added to Gag and the version referenced by your web service ? because I made this mistake few times.

Comment: I did not touch the Web.Config at all. How to add references there? And the version number of the referenced assemblies are correct. The compiler places them in the /project/bin directory and I copied them from there to the %system32% folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-engineered the project structure in VisualStudio to get rid of the dependency to AForder.Video.FFMPEG.DLL. That helped. I found no other solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL' **or one of its dependencies.**

You are either copying the file(s) to the wrong place or not copying the correct files.

Get to the bottom of this by downloading [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

You can then drag `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL` into the application and it will tell you what is missing.

Also, determine the base directory for your application to ensure you are copying the files to the correct folder at runtime. You can do this by writing `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to the console (or add it to your watch)

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598323/aforge-video-ffmpeg-used-in-c-sharp)